# Count letters in string python

Tags: python, windows

(New to python and stack overflow)

I was curious if there was a way to count the amount of letters in a string for python. for example:

```
string="hello"
```

I just want something to count the letters then output it into a variable for later use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will give the length of a string:

```
len(string)
```

In your case, you can assign it:

```
numLetters = len(string)
```

This function can be used for other objects besides strings.  For additional uses, read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len).

Answer (score 1):

Use python function `len`, i.e.:

```
size = len(string)
```

---

```
len()
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len

---

**DEMO**

https://ideone.com/mhpdLi